# Check if any part of string is contained within Text File

Tags: python, string, substring

Here is my code:

```
    for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
        for folder in d:
            folders.append(os.path.join(r, folder))

    for f in folders:
        with open('search.txt') as file:
            contents = file.read()
            if f in contents:
                print ('word found')
```

I'm having the script search through a given directory, and compare the name of the paths to a Text Files full of Virus Definitions. I'm trying to get the script to recognise if the name of the file is contained within said text file.

Problem I've found as you can see from the code, it will only work with a complete match, and as it takes the path as the string (for example; "C:/test/virus.bat") it will never match.

Is it possible to adjust this code so that any part of the path can be matched against the text file?

Not sure if that makes sense, any suggestions welcome or please say if not clear.

EDIT:

To be more clear, here is a logic version of what I am trying to achieve:

- List all Files in Directory
- Get file name within path name ("virus" within "C:/test/virus")
- Check if file name is contained within Text File

Comment: maybe instead of using the `in` you should be using something like [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match)

Comment: @BaronMartin, welcome to StackOverFlow. Some information is not clear. Can you share what exactly are you trying to achieve?..perhaps an example would help.

Comment: @mbieren That's a good point. In that case, how would I take just the last part of the path string, for example, just "virus" rather than "C:/test/virus"?

Comment: When you loop over your `folders` there is no file in the list? Is that supposed to be?

Comment: @BaronMartin `f.split('/')[-1]` can get you the `virus`

Comment: @Albo thank you, I will try this.

Comment: @Albo doesn't seem to work

Comment: You can use `os.path.basename("C:/test/virus")` to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to get all files in a given path:

```py
files = []
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for folder in d:
        if f:
            for file in f:
                files.append(os.path.join(r, folder, file).replace('\\', '/'))
```

then slightly modify your code to achieve the result. You want to check if the content of the file is in the given file path, not vice versa -> `if content in f`:

```py
for f in files:
    with open('search.txt', 'r') as file:
        content = file.read()
        if content in f:
            print('Found')
```

Comment: @BaronMartin can you tell me if this has helped or could you please mark the answer as correct if it helped?